# Efficency of Animating SVG elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I'm new to using javascript for animations, and reciently put this together:

http://www.degeneratestate.org/posts/2016/May/01/visualising-hypercubes/

Essentially I'm updating the positions of a large number of SVG elements in a loop. The animation appears smooth until you have more then a few hundred elements. Looking at profiles of the animations, the most time consuming step is the step which loops through each element and updates their positions.

Being new to javascript, I don't know whether I am missing a more efficient way to do this.

Am I just trying to animate too many elements at once? Should I be using a different method display them (e.g. canvas)?

Comment: Here's a good read about SVG and canvas: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193983(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: might depend on if everything moves the same direction/amount or if everything moves different...

Comment: SMIL and CSS animation is a slightly efficient as UAs can predict the future of the animations.Updating via the SVG DOM rather than setAttribute is also better as it avoids the UAs parser.